# DirectX11 Loaded texture colour becomes more saturated

Tags: directx-11

I'm loading an image to the screen using DirectX11, but the image becomes more saturated. Left is the loaded image and right is the original image.

[image]

Strange thing is that this happens only when I'm loading large images. The resolution of the image I'm trying to print is 1080 x 675 and my window size is 1280 x 800. Also, although the original image has a high resolution the image becomes a little pixelated. This is solved if I use LINEAR filter but I'm curious why this is happening. I'm fairly new to DirectX and I'm struggling..

Vertex data:

```
_vertices[0].p = { -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
//_vertices[0].c = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
_vertices[0].t = { 0.0f, 0.0f };

_vertices[1].p = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
//_vertices[1].c = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
_vertices[1].t = { 1.0f, 0.0f };

_vertices[2].p = { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f };
//_vertices[2].c = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
_vertices[2].t = { 0.0f, 1.0f };

_vertices[3].p = { 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f };
//_vertices[3].c = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
_vertices[3].t = { 1.0f, 1.0f };
```

Vertex layout:

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC elementDesc[] = {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        //{ "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        { "TEXTURE", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 28, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    };
```

Sampler state:

```
 D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC samplerDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&samplerDesc, sizeof(samplerDesc));
    samplerDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT;
    samplerDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    samplerDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    samplerDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    device->CreateSamplerState(&samplerDesc, &g_defaultSS);
```

Vertex shader:

```
struct VS_IN
{
    float3 p : POSITION; 
    //float4 c : COLOR;
    float2 t : TEXTURE;
};

struct VS_OUT
{
    float4 p : SV_POSITION;
    //float4 c : COLOR0;
    float2 t : TEXCOORD0;
};

VS_OUT VSMain(VS_IN input) 
{
    VS_OUT output = (VS_OUT)0;
    output.p = float4(input.p, 1.0f);
    //output.c = input.c;
    output.t = input.t;
    return output;
}
```

Pixel shader:

```
Texture2D     g_texture         : register(t0);
SamplerState  g_sampleWrap      : register(s0);
float4 PSMain(VS_OUT input) : SV_Target
    {
        float4 vColor = g_texture.Sample(g_sampleWrap, input.t);    
        return vColor; //* input.c;
    }
```

Comment: The colour of the image that DirectX renders is different to the original because the pixel shader is outputting the sampled pixel value `vColor` multiplied by some other value in `input.c`. Try just returning `vColor`. Also, a linear filter samples more than one texel from your image and returns an interpolated value, which smooths the image.

Comment: @MaicoDeBlasio Thanks for your explanation about linear filter. I removed every code about vertex color (both in vertex and pixel shader), but I'm still getting a saturated image. Could there be any other reasons for this?

Comment: My guess is that you have a color space conversion issue. Typically image file types like PNG store color in "gamma space". Color computations in the pixel shader however should be performed in "linear space". If you use a DXGI format with an `_SRGB` extension for your SRV, DirectX will perform the color space conversion for you automatically.

Comment: @MaicoDeBlasio Thank you! The issue was solved using a WIC_LOADER_FLAG. Have a nice day :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely an issue of colorspace. If rendering using 'linear colors' (which is recommended), then likely your image is in sRGB colorspace. You can let the texture hardware deal with the gamma by using `DXGI_FORMAT_*_SRGB` formats for your texture, or you can do it directly in the shader.

See these resources:

[Linear-Space Lighting (i.e. Gamma)](http://filmicworlds.com/blog/linear-space-lighting-i-e-gamma/)

[Chapter 24. The Importance of Being Linear](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-iv-image-effects/chapter-24-importance-being-linear), GPU Gems 3

[Gamma-correct rendering](https://blog.molecular-matters.com/2011/11/21/gamma-correct-rendering/)

> In the *DirectX Tool Kit*, you can do various load-time tricks as well. See [DDSTextureLoader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DDSTextureLoader) and [WICTextureLoader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/WICTextureLoader).